# Sorry, but something went wrong. Please contact the seller. Issue : when checkout with credit card (Authorized.net) - Magento-2.1.2

Tags: checkout, authorize.net, magento-2.1.2

I am using Magento ver. 2.1.2. Some of our customer complain that they can't checkout with Credit Card (Authorize.net). A sorry message "sorry but something went wrong" showing when checkout. We have checked the issue also found the problem using credit card (testing mode).

But when I check in admin, order was placed as Pending status.

[image]

I have contacted with the theme (Porto) support section, but they replied that "payment method integration is core functionality of Magento default, not theme related". So, they are are unable to help about this issue.

Can you please help me resolve the issue.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error generally comes when server connection timeout of api has been expired. For authorize.net it is 45 second. you can check it from here:

`Magento\Authorizenet\Model\TransactionService` `CONNECTION_TIMEOUT`

there are two option for solve this problem you can check by increase your timeout or check with your authorize.net team.

Comment: Hi @Yogesh
Thanks for your response. I have increased the response time of `vendor/magento/module-authorizenet/Model/TransactionService.php` `const CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 60;` but no luck.

Comment: I have checked the error log that showing the below response in `debug.log`. no other error in `system.log` and `exception.log`. `[2017-06-16 10:30:45] main.DEBUG: per product type 5.9500 simple {"is_exception":false}[]
[2017-06-16 10:30:45] main.DEBUG: per product type 5.9500 simple {"is_exception":false} []
[2017-06-16 10:30:50] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: {"method":"POST","url":"https://fbms.com/authorizenet/directpost_payment/place/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["catalog_product_1376","FPC"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []`

Comment: And I also checked the server response using browser's inspector for the response of the transact.dll, given below. `< HTML >
< BODY >
< TABLE >
< TR >< TD >An error occurred while trying to report this transaction to the merchant. 
An e-mail has been sent to the merchant informing them of the error. 
The following is the result of the attempt to charge your credit card. 
< BR >< BR >This transaction has been approved.< BR >
< P >It is advisable for you to contact the merchant to verify 
that you will receive the product or service.< BR ></ TD ></ TR >

</ HTML >`

Comment: try with cache enable, it may be occurred due to long response time

Comment: Hi @Yogesh, 
Thanks for your information. Finally the problem is fixed.

Comment: @PkRay what was the problem, I am facing same issue with porto theme.

Comment: @AleksaŽivković Think you recently applied some htaccess rules to block unwanted bots of search engine. If you did this, please remove the unnecessary rules form the .htaccess file. Hope it will solve the problem. If it works please let me..

Comment: HI @PkRay, How did you solve the issue,

Answer (score 2):

I've also experienced the same issue in Magento ver 2.1.2 Opensource. It was due to payment transaction is to long and exceeded the timeout which is 30sec. In my case I've increased the timeout time to 60sec in

Magento\Payment\Model\IframeConfigProvider::TIMEOUT_TIME

Answer (score 0):

Following solution worked for me.
I have upgraded the module by php bin/magento setup:upgrade
Also, make sure the api urls should be following

Gateway URL  https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll ,
Transaction Details URL https://api2.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api