# Magento 2: Payment Gateway error, Sorry, but something went wrong. Please contact the seller. Issue (Authorized.net)

Tags: magento2, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I got an error on payment gateway in magento 2, `Sorry, but something went wrong. Please contact the seller`(Authorized.net), 
I am using the sandbox account for authorized.net.

[image]

Got the same error like mentioned in this question: 
[Sorry, but something went wrong. Please contact the seller. Issue : when checkout with credit card (Authorized.net) - Magento-2.1.2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/179206/sorry-but-something-went-wrong-please-contact-the-seller-issue-when-checkou/179244)

I also changed the time in `60` in this
`Magento\Authorizenet\Model\TransactionService CONNECTION_TIMEOUT`

and also my cache is enabled.

> Note: I am running project on localhost, if this is the reason for
>   that?

please suggest a solution.

Comment: Authorize.net doesn't work on the local environment, you won't get a response from `transact.dll`. Try to use "online" environment.